# Pyspark unable to overwrite csv in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I am facing issue when i try to write file in S3 as CSV.
I am basically trying to overwrite existing single csv file in an S3 folder. Below is the peice of code in I'm running.
[image]

I am getting below error. My wild guess is this is due to single file present in S3 folder. While overwriting it first deletes existing file which further deletes the S3 folder since there is no file inside it. And then it couldn't create file since no folder exists with given name. Hence whole overwriting fails.

[image]

Any help to resolve this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: is there any error in the python (spark) code? the error snapshot you've pasted seems to be from s3 or athena

Comment: I'm working in glue. Script and it's code doesn't have any error. Seems like, It's not able to read from a file and over write on same.

Comment: spark will create a folder while writing the file if it isn't present. so, i'm guessing it's some permission issue

Comment: It is not a permission issue because I'm able to read and write from nearby folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this issue didn't resolve, had to do work around. Seems like this issue is not with S3, the issue is of spark. Once you read a csv using Spark, you cannot write over the same csv until you read some other csv.

Work around looked like below:

1. Read from root/myfolder
2. Make your data transformations
3. Write transform the data into root/mytempfolder
4. Read from root/mytempfolder
5. Write into root/myfolder

Answer (score 0):

Caching the dataset solves the problem and you don't need to save the same data into multiple paths

`dataframe.cache()`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).